# High cross validation score but low model performance on test set

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, overfitting, boosting, credit-scoring

I'm doing a machine learning project and need to predict a user's credit default probability. I tried some simple automated feature engineering and got a good AUC score on training set using stratified cross validation. However, my model performed poorly on unseen test set with AUC 0.66. See below:

[image]

Here are some details about my data and model:

- In my training data, each row represents a user along with over 500 features I generated.
- My data set is imbalanced and that's why I used stratified cross validation
- There is no time series so there shouldn't be any trends in the data.
- I don't think there is any problem with the unseen test set as I tried manual feature engineering and another model which got a score of 0.71
- I used LGBM Classifier. Here is my model:

model=lgb.LGBMClassifier(n_estimators=1000,objective='binary',class_weight='balanced',learning_rate=0.05,reg_lambda=0.1,subsample=0.8)

I tried to reduce the number of estimators but that only reduced 'train_auc' and auc on unseen test set became even worse. It would be much appreciated if someone could suggest any reason or remedy to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you perform your feature engineering on the entire training set (not inside each fold)?

Comment: Yes. I did feature engineering before cross validation.

Comment: That may be it: your feature engineering procedure is overfitted on the training data. But, that doesn't strike me as being enough for that large a drop in AUC, unless your engineering has high capacity?